# Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd'

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, xsd

I want to use Spring security so configured like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <http>
        <intercept-url pattern="/add-job**" access="hasRole('USER')" />
        <form-login />
        <logout />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
            <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

but I'm getting errors as

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>       - schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/
>        security/spring-security-4.0.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) 
>        the root element of the document is not .
>       - cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 
>        'http'.

and

and my pom.xml for Security is

```
<!-- Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

I can not find way to fix this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Answering Guys, but finally I've found a solution at [Migrating from Spring Security 3.x to 4.x (XML Configuration)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-update-security), and found the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

this with along side of mentioned in Question, this approach solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Spring recommends to use this `http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd` instead specifying version number, as you do with `spring-beans`.

This way, I have a project with the same spring security dependencies, but instead `4.0.2.RELEASE` I have `4.0.1.RELEASE` and it is working with no problems.

So you have to try schema configuration as follows:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd"
```

If it doesn't work, then you may have a transitive dependency problem and you are simply loading two or more different spring security versions. In this case try using `mvn dependency:tree` to see if you have more than one spring-security depedency on `configuration` artifact, and exclude the one you don't need.

Comment: This is strange, as I told you I have very similar project with both dependencies. I just run dependency tree and I see `spring-security-core` is include transitively by `spring-security-web` with the same version, not with `4.0.0.RELEASE`. It is working for me this way.